# Who does "they" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, pronouns, antecedents

> “I never wanna be the guy who stops loving someone for loving the way that **they** want to love”

---

Who does "they" refer to,  "the guy" or "someone"?

P.S.  This sentence is from a movie line, when a boy finds out the girl he loves is gay, he is very sad, but eventually he decides to continue loving the girl even though she is gay and says this line to the girl.

Comment: This is a confusing sentence that doesn't really scan.  Could you give some context or the source?

Comment: Looks like "they" is representing the someone here, perhaps the person he is talking about or talking to.

Comment: From your explanation - yes, _they_ is obviously the girl.